# Trying to dismiss UIAlertController with unknown presenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, stack-trace

My application crashed, and it must be because of UIAlertController.

This issue occurs only on iOS 8.x where UIAlertController is available.  The strange fact is that **my application does not use UIAlertViewController nor UIAlertView**.

The reports tell me:

```
Trying to dismiss UIAlertController <UIAlertController: 0x172c5d80> with unknown presenter.
```

How this can happen?

I thought about

1. Undo System AlertView displayed thanks to the shake gesture
2. WebView deallocated while a prompt or a generic dialog is still on screen
3. Low battery alert

but not one of this cases drive me to the crash.

What the crash log suggests to me is the fact that the OS shows an AlertView that will be attached to my application window and in some circumstances loose the parent view controller that presented the UIAlertViewController.

Any ideas how to find the issue?

Here the stack trace

```
_________________________________
0    CoreFoundation                         0x2bc0c45f __exceptionPreprocess + 127
1    libobjc.A.dylib                        0x39c79c8b objc_exception_throw + 36
2    CoreFoundation                         0x2bc0c3a5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 110
3    UIKit                                  0x2f4ad13d -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 414
4    UIKit                                  0x2f4acf97 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:] + 28
5    UIKit                                  0x2f590a0b -[_UIAlertControllerActionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 160
6    UIKit                                  0x2f159567 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
7    UIKit                                  0x2f152e31 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 542
8    UIKit                                  0x2f129759 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 194
9    UIKit                                  0x2f39d2f9 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14166
10   UIKit                                  0x2f1281a9 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1350
11   CoreFoundation                         0x2bbd2fbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
12   CoreFoundation                         0x2bbd23cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 216
13   CoreFoundation                         0x2bbd0a35 __CFRunLoopRun + 770
14   CoreFoundation                         0x2bb1e3b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
15   CoreFoundation                         0x2bb1e1c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
16   GraphicsServices                       0x3308d201 GSEventRunModal + 134
17   UIKit                                  0x2f18843d UIApplicationMain + 1438
18   MyApp                                  0x00028a07 main (main.mm:16)
```

**EDIT**

holes asked about my window initialisation. Here the code of my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[MyAppCustomWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    _mainViewController = [[MyAppContainerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _mainStatusBarVC = [[MyAppStatusBarVC alloc] initWithRootVC:_mainViewController];

    [self.window setRootViewController:_mainStatusBarVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: how have you inited your `UIWindow` instance for your app?

Comment: I initialised MyCustomWindow in my AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: Then I set the rootViewController and made it key and visible using self.window makeKeyAndVisible. I will edit the question with some code about it.

Comment: Added the code about MyCustomWindow initialisation.
I'm interested in reproduce the issue in order to be sure any kind of code fix will fix the issue for sure.
I have no idea why an UIAlertViewController is showed in my application stack trace.

Comment: I don't see it from what you have presented. There has to be something else causing it.

Comment: Exactly ... I miss what is presenting this system alert. Have to be a system process that interferes in some way with my application but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries?

Comment: The only "closed" third party library I use is Crittercism but the "Rate Alert" for my Crittercism App ID is disabled, I'm just using it for crash reports using a basic account. Lib version 4.0.6.

Comment: do you use UIActionSheet?

Comment: No, I don't use UIActonSheet at all.

Comment: Do you use popovers? I have seen a similar issue where the popover was not held as a property of the controller raising the popover.

Comment: I use some popover controllers but I have no crash on this components. How can this interact with a system UIAlertController? Any suggest @RoryMcKinnel?

Comment: Well from what you have said, you do not use UIAlertController yourself. So something in the system code must be trying to use one for some reason and has failed to do so for the error given. I mentioned popovers, because I have seen mention of a similar error and it was related to popovers. I just looked at your stack trace and the stack also mentions: `-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 414`. So it looks like the trigger may well be a popover. Try making all the popovers that you create properties of the class raising them.

Comment: Ok. I thought you have had a similar issue using popoverController. About my stacktrace I think "popover" in the private UIAlertController message signature is not related to something that happens using popovers. I think is the normal internal flow used by the UIAlertController to dismiss the View. I will try as soon as I can to use an UIAlertController by myself and watch the internal code flow while dismissing it ... just to see if the private UIAlertController chunk of code is ran everytime.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I tested right now a simple UIAlertController on a blank project. Setting a breakpoint inside the action block and tapping the action the internal flow of UIAlertController drives me to `-[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:]` ... So I deduct that there is nothing in common with UIPopoverController ... it's just the name of an internal method.

Comment: Ok. Out of interest, it looks like you are creating your own UIWindow? I believe if you are using storyboard ( which you may not be) you shoudl create additional windows and not override the original. If so try adding a property self.window1 and allocate that, set its root and make it visible. Could be there is a dependency on the original window which you are blowing away?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel No MyApp does not use storyboard and Yes MyApp use a custom window. It's allocated in `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and stored in the `window` property of MyAppDelegate derived by the `UIApplicationDelegate` This is the sole window in the normal application usage. A new `UIWindow` is showed when MyApp must show a completely custom MyAlertView (subclass of `UIView` ... completely unaware of `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController`)

Comment: Why do you need to create a new UIWindow for your custom MyAlertView?  I do not believe you should have more than one UIWindow in your app per screen. Does the crash happen following the usage of your custom MyAlertView? I think you will need to add more detail of what you have to do to cause the crash.

Comment: I can't give you some more hits about the crash because I don't know how to reproduce it. It's something that happens in production but it's never happened while developing. The purpose of the question is understand what cause the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76472/discussion-between-gabriele-and-rory-mckinnel).

Answer (score 2):

I bet your crash occurred on iPad.

On iPad, from iOS8, UIActionSheet seem to be handled with a `UIAlertController`

With this code,

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) return; // Cancel button

    [self doSomeViewControllerDismisses];
}
```

My app was crashing with the same error you got.
To prevent this, I just dispatch the complex dismiss call on the next MainThread execution, to give to the hidden `UIAlertViewController` the opportunity to release properly.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) return; // Cancel button

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doSomeViewControllerDismisses];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the hint. Unfortunately my app do not use UIActionSheet at all

Comment: Do your app uses popovers (`UIPopoverController`)? I think Apple devs reused this `UIAlertController` in several other UIKit controls, like popovers too.

Comment: Yes I use it. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

A stack trace of this form generally indicates that you have navigated away from a UIViewController whilst an alert that you had it present is still dismissing.

The general remedy for that is to present or dismiss controllers in UIAlertViewDelegate's alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: method, since then you're sure that the presenter won't go away during any dismissal.

In your case, if you can't find any reproducible case you could try checking presentedViewController before presenting/dismissing a controller and see if that turns anything up.

But probably if you audit your controller transitions you'll find somewhere that responding to a system alert could programmatically trigger a navigation. Do you have any functionality that throws up a system alert for user authorization, like access to photos or whatever, and them denying it would result in a controller being programmatically dismissed by your error handling? That seems like a reasonably plausible scenario.

Comment: As written my entire code does not use UIAlertViewController at all. The only third party library I can't access the source code is criticism. I experimented that in same case, I don't know when, crittercism raise the location tracking confirmation alert to the user. Cause I don't know when the Crittercism library try to access it, I tried by myself emulating the crittercism possible LocationManager ownship as described in the next comment.

Comment: MyAppDelegate retain the locationManager while a modal presented viewController request the authorisation to use location functionality. 
This cause the system tracking alert to show. Now I can dismiss the modal controller by a remote functionality available on my app. This will cause the modal view controller to dismiss while the tracking alert is still on screen.
Tapping any of the two buttons of the alert, cancel or allow, my app still run with no bad consequence.

Comment: Anyway based on your answer I have another question. Are you sure that using iOS SDK API that present a system popup, as location tracking or photos access, I can find the UIViewController checking presentedViewController on the currently  displayed view controller? I don't think so ... I did not test it right now but it seems strange to me that I have to care about in my own code about something the iOS generates by its own. Sure it could be an iOS 8 bug but if it is I'm surprised that I never encountered it in any of the thousand applications I run on my iOS devices using iOS 8.

Comment: Under any normal circumstances, it shouldn't. But since you're quite sure that the alert controller that's crashing isn't yours, my "reasonably plausible" guess for how it could produce the provided crash log is that it's getting confused and using one of your controllers that goes away, instead of whatever it should be presenting off of.

Answer (score 0):

try to dismiss on main thread Alertview  using Block on main thrad.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
  //  Write your alert view code in swift language .
})
```

Comment: The question is how can myApp crash on UIAlertController if myApp does not use UIAlertController at all ...